# Ansible cannot connect to host via specified private key

Tags: ansible

The following command works from my OSX terminal:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.50.100 -i .vagrant/machines/centos100/virtualbox/private_key
```

I have an inventory file called "hosts" with the following:

> 192.168.50.100 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/centos100/virtualbox/private_key

However when I run the following:

```
ansible -i hosts all -m ping -v
```

I get: 
192.168.50.100 | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ansible 1.8.2 where ansible_user is still ansible_ssh_user

The correct hosts file is:

> 192.168.50.100 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/centos100/virtualbox/private_key